# Почему DataInputStream читает из фала записанного в одном запуске с записью?

Tags: java, io

У меня очень странная ситуация: я использую `DataInputStream` для чтения из файла строка в `UTF8`. В случае если я прямо перед этим записал в файл чтение все работает, а если хочу просто прочесть уже записанное падает с ошибкой.

Вот этот код работает:

```
private void read() {
    String path = "/Users/pavel/Desktop/test/target_text.txt";
    try (DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(path));
         DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(path))) {

            out.writeUTF("hello");

            String data = in.readUTF();

            System.out.println(data);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

А вот так уже не работает:

```
private void read() {
    String path = "/Users/pavel/Desktop/test/target_text.txt";
    try (DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(path));
         DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(path))) {

            //out.writeUTF("hello"); // причем я только что записывал 
           //этим методом и знаю что записан файл по правилу  UTF8


            String data = in.readUTF();

            System.out.println(data);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Падает с ошибкой:

```
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedShort(DataInputStream.java:340)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:589)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:564)
```

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться в чем моя ошибка? Как мне просто прочесть данные методом `readUTF()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создание объекта класса `FileOutputStream` с помощью конструктора:

```
public FileOutputStream(String name)
```

подразумевает запись данных в **начало** файла, соответственно, после выполнения этой операции содержимое файла будет очищено, следовательно, далее, при создании объекта класса `FileInputStream`:

```
new FileInputStream(path)
```

Вы считываете уже пустой файл и справедливо получаете `EOFException` при попытке чтения.

Варианты решения проблемы:

1. Создавать объект класса `FileOutputStream` с помощью конструктора:

   ```
   public FileOutputStream(String name, boolean append)
   ```

   с флагом `append == true`. В этом случае, данные будут записываться в **конец** файла, следовательно, первоначальное содержимое файла будет сохранено и Вы сможете успешно его считать с помощью `FileInputStream`.
2. Убрать `DataOutputStream` (этот случай подходит, если Вам не требуется в этом фрагменте кода что-то писать в файл).

Comment: >>>FileOutputStream(String name) одразумевает запись данных в начало файла, соответственно, после выполнения этой операции содержимое файла будет удалено<<< но когда я заглядываю в файл текстовым редактором там искомый текст есть ничего не удалено а читать не хочет, может быть мы о разном говорим? в файле контент есть это точно

Comment: @Павел, Поставьте брейк-поинт на первую строчку метода `read()` и пройдитесь по методу отладчиком. После выполнения каждой строки смотрите содержимое файла.

Comment: А спасибо большое, я понял код не работает если я оставляю не закоментированым DataOutputStream и не использую его тогда он просто очищает файл! Правильно?

Comment: @Павел, Да, верно.